# Read RabbitMQ Messages on Azure

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a local machine that reads RabbitMQ queue messages.

I wish to move it to cloud. Which Azure service can be used in this case?

I went through event hubs, but I am not sure, if it would read messages from rabbitMQ continuously.

Any suggestions for the service that should be put to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Azure [Service Bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/service-bus/). It has got FIFO queues as well as publish/subscribe capabilities. However if using Azure managed service is not a strict requirement you can use RabbitMQ on a VM (or a cluster for high availability) as well.

UPDATE: Your response means you want a managed service. There are 2 options - if you want to go with RabbitMQ but do not want to manage the infrastructure you can go for 3rd party service provider like [CloudAMQP](https://www.cloudamqp.com/) who will manage it on your behalf. The other option is to go for Cloud native messaging - meaning if you are on Azure you change your messaging service to Azure Service Bus. This would mean changing you code as well.

Comment: my current setup is on a virtual machine. it reads the data continously. The process runs with a systemd service...I want it to move that to cloud...but not on a VM

Comment: cloudamqp is a queue producer, I am looking only for a reader.

Comment: What do you mean by queue producer ?

Comment: So there are 2 things here. One is message producer and second one is a consumer. Producer is a third party service in place. Consumer is not able to catch up with producer. I need a solution whereby entire produced data is ingested by consumer.

Comment: You then need to scale your consumers...maybe increase the number of nodes or threads which consumer is using. Same problem you will have anywhere either on-prem or on Cloud.